# Не могу получить натуральные размеры картинки naturalWidth

Tags: javascript

Господа, в данном примере как видно, я получаю то что хочу, а вот у меня на компьютере, отнюдь...  Картинка с результатом.  Есть идеи почему так?
Кстати, пример на компе, обычный HTML на рабочем столе...

И в chome и FF один и тот же результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
console.log(img1.naturalWidth)
```

```html
<img width="100" height="100" id="img1" class="img" src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg" alt="A">
```

Comment: Может картинка не успевает подгружаться?

Comment: Дмытрык, ты гений))))  точно....  `setTimeout` помог

Comment: не надо `setTimeout`. это будет разно при разной скорости интернета.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, знаю, в данном случае `setTimeout` использовано для выявление проблемы, а не для решения ее

Comment: кстати говоря, тоже самое и когда картинки не из сети подгружаются, а находятся в папке тоже на рабочем столе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо просто использовать `onload`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
  var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
  img1.onload = function(){
    console.log(img1.naturalWidth)
  };
});
```

```html
<img width="100" height="100" id="img1" class="img" src="http://www.visitcalifornia.com/sites/default/files/styles/welcome_image/public/VCW_D_Bigsur_T2_CC_BigSurBeach_Miller-1280x642.jpg" alt="A">
```

Comment: Твой ответ адекватнее...))))

Comment: Вопрос для общего развития: для чего .onload после DOMContentLoaded (хотелось бы понять)

Comment: Все, понял, почитал документацию :)

Comment: @VladVityuk Вот и хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Событие onload на window срабатывает, когда загружается вся страница, включая ресурсы на ней – стили, картинки, ифреймы и т.п.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    console.log(img1.naturalWidth)
}
```

```html
<img width="100" height="100" id="img1" class="img" src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg" alt="A">
```

з.ы. отредактировал.

Comment: Опять на первый раз выдал `0`

Comment: Vlad Vityuk, у тебя в консоли тот же результат, какой у меня в компе))))

Comment: Да, тупанул, load тут не подходит.

Comment: И опять у меня 0 после того как вы изменили ответ

Comment: Перечитал, данный способ работает в 90% случаев. Исправил еще раз

Answer (score -1):

Оказалось, все просто....  Картинка не успевает догрузиться....
Особое спасибо  Дмытрык-у....

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(img1.naturalWidth)
}, 5000)
```

```html
<img width="100" height="100" id="img1" class="img" src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg" alt="A">
```